# fixing ASP.NET website that works in IE6, to work in IE8

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer-8, compatibility-mode

I need to fix a ASP.NET website that works in IE6, to work in IE8 browser. I added the EmulateIE7 http header to IIS6 as short term fix, but still the pages are not displayed correctly. the web app was initially designed and developed for IE6, now we are upgrading to IE8, so is there any quick fix available for IE6 website to display correctly in IE8? I thought the EmulateIE7 works for both IE7 and previous versions as well, is that not correct?

regards,

Rama

Comment: What is wrong with it on IE8? Do you get any error message?  How extensively are you using javascripts?

Comment: EmulateIE7 does exactly what it says. I assume your app does not work in IE7 either

Comment: I haven't tested it in extensively in IE8, but page layout seems to be the main issue at the moment. I haven't tested it in IE7. right now I am looking for short term solution for quick release of the app to the users to get around this. later the code will changed to be compliant with standards mode.

Answer (score 0):

I can't remember exactly what level of CSS IE6 uses. You could maybe try telling IE8 to render the page as IE5 did by using the following META tag in each page:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=IE5" />
```

If this is site wide, then add it as an HTTP header in the web server itself.